# Google Rich Snippets warnings for hCard

Tags: schema.org, vcf-vcard, google-rich-snippets, hcard

I get the following errors from the Google Rich Snippet Tool for my website http://iancrowther.co.uk/

> hcard
>   Warning: This information will not appear as a rich snippet in search results results, because it seems to describe an organization. Google does not currently display organization information in rich snippets
>   Warning: At least one field must be set for Hcard.
>   Warning: Missing required field "name (fn)".

Im experimenting with vcard and Schema.org and am wondering if I'm missing something or the validator is playing up.  I have added vcard and Schema.org markup to the `body` which may be causing confusion.  Also, I am making the assumption I can use both methods to markup my code.

---

Update:

I guess with the `body` tag, I'm just trying to let Google discover the elements which make up the schema object within the page.  I'm not sure if this is a good / bad way to approach things? However it lets my markup be free of specific blocks of markup.  I guess this is open to discussion but I like the idea of having a natural flow to the content that's decorated in the background.  Do you think there is any negative impact? I'm undecided.

I am in favour of the Person structure, this was a good call as this is more representative of the current site content.  I am a freelance developer and as such use this page as my Organisation landing page, so I guess I have to make a stronger decision of the sites goals and tailor the content accordingly, ie Organisation or Person.

I understand that there is no immediate rich snippet gains, but im a web guy so have a keen interest in these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

With schema testing, I find it easiest to start from the most obvious problem, and try to work our way deeper from there. Note, I have zero experience with hcard, but I don't believe the error you mentioned actually has anything to do with your hcard properties.

The most obvious problem I see, is that your body tag has an itemtype of `schema.org\Organization`. When you set an itemtype on a dom element, you are saying that everything inside of that element is going to help describe that itemtype. Since you've placed this on your body element, you are quite literally telling Google that your entire page is about an organization.

From the content of your page, I would recommend changing that itemtype to `schema.org\Person`. This would seem to be a more accurate description. Once you make that change and run the scanner again, you may see more errors relating to the schema and we can work through those too (for example, you'll probably need to set familname and givenName).

With all of that said, you should know that currently there are no rich snippets that you will gain from adding this schema data. Properly setting this up on your page, is only good to do, especially since we don't know what rich snippets Google or others will expose in the future, but currently you won't see any additional rich snippets in Google search results from adding these tags. I don't want to discourage you from setting this up properly but I just want to set your expectations.

Comment: I have updated the question to provide some feedback based on your response if your interested.